# Trying to install Blueprint with Compass

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I'm trying to install Blueprint with Compass but it's not working.

I search on different websites/forums and I'm not finding my answer.

My issue:

```
$ gem install compass-blueprint
Fetching: compass-blueprint-0.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed compass-blueprint-0.0.1
1 gem installed

$ compass frameworks
Available Frameworks & Patterns:

* compass
- compass/ellipsis  - Plugin for cross-browser ellipsis truncated text.
- compass/extension - Generate a compass extension.
- compass/pie       - Integration with http://css3pie.com/
- compass/project   - The default project layout.


$ compass install blueprint
No such framework: "blueprint" // Understandable, the framework is not in the list
```

The blueprint framework is not available in the list of frameworks of compass.

I'm using Compass 0.13.alpha.4

Any idea to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blueprint was removed from compass in 0.13.

http://compass-style.org/blog/2012/05/20/removing-blueprint/